# camel case json to snake case json in scala/java

Tags: scala, jackson, objectmapper

I have a JSON object where the keys are in camel case inside a string in scala, and I want to convert it to snake case json (where keys are in snake case) string. Is there a clean way to do it? I was looking at Jackson object mapper and finatra object mapper but couldnt figure it out.

I can't map it to the underlying java class and then use the object mapper to retrieve a json string because the underlying class is generated by apache avro and when I try to do that object mapper throws up with exceptions, perhaps getting confused by some generated code.

Comment: take a look at jackson-dataformats-binary. It support arvo. 


https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-

Answer (score 3):

So json4s seems to have what i asked for. here is what the code looks like

```
  import org.json4s._
  import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

  val snakeKeyJsonAST = parse(camelKeyJsonString).snakizeKeys
  val snakeKeyJsonString = compact(render(snakeKeyJsonAST))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use play-json, you can use this library.
[play-json-naming](https://github.com/tototoshi/play-json-naming)